# Allocate C file contents into specific memory without update the C file

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I’m using Windriver compiler suite (5.9.3) and I’m programming using C.

I would like to locate constant variables contained into one H/C file into RAM memory

---

**Constraint:**

1. I cannot manually modify the H/C file and so I cannot add pragma to define sections to be used in my linker.
2. The H/C file contains only constant declaration
3. All my code is located into ROM and loaded at startup into RAM

---

**Variable are declared as follows:**

H file: `extern const int toto;`

C file: `const int toto = 1;`

---

**Solution?**

By default, constants are referred as “.text” section, so I have used the -Xconst-in-text=4 compiler option to be able to put constants in “.data” section.
Then I have allocated all “.data” section into RAM memory.Problem is that I have all constants located into RAM memory and not only constants defined into my  H/C file.

I have look for some options to be able to locate only constant from my H/C file into RAM memory but I was not able to succeed. The only option I see would be do modify my makefile and compile my C/H file with the -Xconst-in-text=4 option and all other without this option. This would made the trick by I'm looking for a solution that allows me to compile all files with the -Xconst-in-text=4 option.

Do you have any solutions?

Do you know if I can tell the linker to put all sections for all files except one into a specific memory?

Do you think it would be possible to create a H/C file that would include the H/C file I cannot change and use “pragma define section” in this file (and this pragma to apply to included variables)?

Thanks

Comment: With GCC you could use a custom linker script after compilation to put anything anywhere you wanted it. Not sure if this exists for your compiler.

Comment: Did the -Xconst-in-text=4 option apply to ALL files you compiled or just the H/C file? Using it on just the H/C file would seem to give you what you want.

Comment: I have used the -Xconst option for the specific file. Results are as expected but I was looking for a solution that do not imply makefile update. I have clarified my first post. Thanks